# How to insert and delete cell in tableview

Tags: iphone, ios, tableview

Actually my requirement is , I have data with me and i am showing those on my tableview cell. When i click on any cell the tableview should insert three more cell immediately after the clicked cell and when u click another cell the old one should shrink and expand once again.

Comment: Kindly see **Tip 11** in [this](http://odedcoster.com/blog/2010/07/28/getting-good-answers-on-stackoverflow-part-1-of-n/) link.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use these methods:

```
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:paths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

and

```
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:paths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

where you can set the paths as needed.

```
NSArray *paths = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0], ..., nil];
```

**Update:**

You also need to update `numberOfRowsInSection`. You could set a `BOOL` in your class that tells whether the extra cells are currently showing are hidden, and then check that `BOOL` to know what number to return. For example:

```
if (extraCellsAreShowing) {
    return 4;
}
else {
    return 1;
}
```

Additionally, if you use an array of values for your table view data source, you may need to alter those values as well. I can't really give an example of that as it will depend on your specific situation.

Comment: Yes i am doing same when deleteRowsAtIndexPaths get called the app crashes.

Comment: How to vary the array size while inserting and deleting

Comment: Oh, I think I know what you mean. I will update my answer in a minute.

Comment: @Arundhati you should change your data array before calling the messages above. I recommend you to use `NSMutableArray` and just `insertObject:atPosition:` message.

Comment: when u call the deleteRowsAtIndexPaths the array internally get update i guess

Comment: In this case is it necessary the [tableview updateData] method, or is this done automatically after the insertCell method?

Comment: @mollybaba You can just change the array. The changes will get picked up when `cellForRowAtIndexPath` runs.

Comment: @woz: when array internally get update what's the use to have boolean value in numberOfRowsInsection

Comment: @Arundhati If you are using an array, you don't really need the `BOOL` because you can just return `[array count]`.

Comment: getting errorTerminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (39) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (39), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 3 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Comment: Yes, so your function is still returning 39 and it should be returning 36. You need to track the number of rows your are deleting so you can return the right value in `numberOfRowsInSection`.

Comment: yes i got what the error is but how to decrease those values not getting do i need to do it manually

Comment: Yes, you have to decrease the values yourself (unless you are returning the count of an array).